# open new window in tablet/smartphone

Tags: javascript, html

```
window.open("page.php","fs","fullscreen,no-scrollbars, n")
```

this JavaScript code open new window on PC without scroll as expected. 
When trying to achieve the same on smartphone/tablet it just open the page in a new tab. 
Tested on Android 4.0 and 6.0 with Chrome and with Firefox (downloaded two days ago from google play so i guess they are the latest) - and all acting the same (open page in new tab).

is there a way to open new window like the one get on PC?

note: i am building an app for internal use so i don't care about S.E.O, Accessibility etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no notion of a "window" in mobile browsers, so opening a in a new tab is as close as you can come.